# how to define a c macro that returns a function name according to the argument?

Tags: c, macros

What I currently have

```
#define _CMPLT8 _mm_cmplt_epi8     // int8_t
#define _CMPLT32 _mm_cmplt_epi32   // int32_t
```

What I want (something similar to the following code)

```
#define _CMPLT(T) (                            \
  if(sizeof(T)==1) return _mm_cmplt_epi8       \
  else if(sizeof(T)==4) return _mm_cmplt_epi32 \
  else #error                                  \
)
```

How could I this code?

Comment: in C++ you wouldn't do this with a macro. In C I don't know. Please do not tag C++ for C questions or vice versa. They are two distinct languages

Comment: 1) Do you want to determine the name of the function exactly by the size of the type, or by the type itself? 2) Do you want to get exactly the address of the function (i.e. just its name), or do you want to do something like an overload so that the _CMPLT(T) expression itself calls the appropriate function for the appropriate argument?

Comment: Did you consider `_Generic` of a current version of C? Can't that help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return a string based on a type I'd go for generics:

```
#define _CMPLT(T) \
  _Generic( (T), \
  char: "1", \
  int: "4", \
  default: "0")

int main(void) {
    char a;
    int b;
    printf("%s%s\n", _CMPLT(a), _CMPLT(b));
}
```

But I feel you want to call functions depending on arg type, so in that case:

```
#define _CMPLT(X, Y) _Generic((X), \
    int8_t: _mm_cmplt_epi8(X, Y), \
    int32_t: _mm_cmplt_epi32(X, Y) \
)

int main(void) {
    int8_t a = 0, b = 1;
    int32_t c = 2, d = 3;
    printf("%d%d\n", _CMPLT(a, b), _CMPLT(c, d));
}
```

If you really need to use strings and sizeof, and can use compound statements, would this work for you?

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define _CMPLT(T) ({ \
    switch(sizeof(T)) { \
    case 1: "1"; \
    case 4: "4"; \
    }; \
    "0"; \
})

int main(void) {
    printf("%s%s\n",
        _CMPLT(char), _CMPLT(int));
}
```